# Is there any JS global function for converting string which contains number with underscores as digit separators to number?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need to convert a string with underscore separated decimal number to an octal number in a special way. Is there any built-in JS function for that?

```js
const str = '2_442_5_88';
const result = someFunc(str)['someFunc'](2 'some operator' 2);
console.assert(result === '11242534');
```

The `result` variable should be equal to `11242534`. Only `someName` and `operator` are editable and they could be an unary or binary operator, a number, a string value or the name of class, value, type, etc. Forbidden to introduce several language elements, constructs, and function calls.

Comment: [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) can parse a number as octal if you pass it the proper `radix` as the second argument.  You could write a function that does the string replacements needed first then passes it into `parseInt`.

Comment: `in a special way.` and you expect a built in function for you're special case ?

Comment: What is `(2 'some operator' 2)`?

Comment: Your update makes no sense to me. What do you mean by "editable"? How should they affect the result? And `2 'some operator' 2` is still a syntax error.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Forbidden to introduce several language elements, constructs, and function calls*"? Which language elements and constructs do you refer to? And both `someFunc(str)` and `…['someFunc'](2 + 2)` are function calls, you cannot avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the underscores by using replace, convert to a number, and then use [`Number.toString(radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) (radix is 8 in this case) to convert to an octal number in string format:

```js
const string = '2_442_5_88';
const result = Number(string.replace(/_/g, '')).toString(8);
console.log(result);
console.assert(result === '11242534');
```

Comment: Thanks for help but the point is that changable stuff are only `someFunc` and `some operator`, representation of `result` variable should stay. Forgot to mention that in description, sorry.

Comment: You'll need to explain more, and give an example.

Comment: someName (str) ['someName'] (2 operator 2);
The code above should return a string which equals to `11242534`. Only `someName` and `operator` are editable and they could be an unary or binary operator, a number, a string value or the name of class, value, type, etc. Forbidden to introduce several language elements, constructs, and function calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the underscores and convert the value to an octal string.

```js
var string = '2_442_5_88',
    result = (+string.replace(/_/g, '')).toString(8);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for help but the point is that changable stuff are only `someFunc` and `some operator`, representation of result variable should stay. Forgot to mention that in description, sorry.

Comment: please add an example of the wanted call.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an eval to parse string number with numeric separators:

```
const str = '2_442_5_88'
const result = eval(str).toString(2 << 2)
console.assert(result === '11242534');
```